# How to establish mongodb NodeJS driver connection in typescript that the connections open once

Tags: typescript, mongodb, express, mongodb-nodejs-driver

I keeping getting connection timeout or this email **You are receiving this alert email because connections to your cluster(s) have exceeded 500, and is nearing the connection limit for the M0 cluster Cluster0 in the Project ------ within Organization ------- Org - ------. Please restart your application or log in to your Atlas account to see some suggested solutions.**

here is my connection

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";
import config from "../config/config";

const { dbName, mongoDBUri } = config;

async function connectToDatabase() {
  const connectionOptions = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  };
  const client = await MongoClient.connect(
    mongoDBUri as string,
    connectionOptions
  );

  return {
    client,
    db: client.db(dbName),
  };
}
export default connectToDatabase;
```

```
  import connectToDatabase from "./../databases/database";

  /**
   * @async
   * @static
   * @params
   */
  static notifyAllAdmins = async ({
    title,
    link,
    linkButtonText,
    message,
  }: NotifyAllAdminsI) => {
    const { client } = await connectToDatabase();
    const notificationSchema = {
      title,
      link,
      linkButtonText,
      message,
      timestamp: Date.now(),
      status: {
        isDeleted: false,
        isRead: false,
      },
    };
    const result = await client
      .db("notifications")
      .collection("adminAnnouncements")
      .insertOne(notificationSchema);
    return result.insertedId;
  };
```

Now my question is every time I call to connect to the database a new connection is created and I want one connection to be created and subsequent call to call to connectToDatabase be using the existing connection

this i was able to do with javascript with the code below

Answer (score 0):

After several times of trying here a solution that worked best for me

```
import { MongoClient, Db } from "mongodb";

const { dbName, mongoDBUri } = config;

if (!mongoDBUri) {
  throw new Error(
    "Define the mongoDBUri environment variable inside .env"
  );
}

if (!dbName) {
  throw new Error(
    "Define the dbName environment variable inside .env"
  );
}

type MongoConnection = {
  client: MongoClient;
  db: Db;
};

declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      mongodb: {
        conn: MongoConnection | null;
        promise: Promise<MongoConnection> | null;
      };
    }
  }
}
let cached = global.mongodb;
if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongodb = { conn: null, promise: null };
}
export default async function connectToDatabase() {
  if (cached.conn) {
    return cached.conn;
  }

  if (!cached.promise) {
    console.log("Establishing new database connection");
    const opts = {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    };

    cached.promise = MongoClient.connect(mongoDBUri as string, opts).then(
      (client) => {
        return {
          client,
          db: client.db(dbName),
        };
      }
    );
  }
  cached.conn = await cached.promise;
  return cached.conn;
}
```